# Подключение библиотек

Tags: c++, eclipse, функции, библиотеки

В eclipse функции `puts`, `printf`, `fprintf`, `exit` подчеркивает красным с надписью `function could not be resolved`. Какие библиотеки должны быть подключены, чтобы не было ошибок? Дополняя информацию еще скажу, что в `Project Explorer` только отображается `libpq-fe.h`. Прилагаю код программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main() {
PGconn          *conn;
PGresult        *res;
int             rec_count;
int             row;
int             col;

conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.143.93 port=5432 connect_timeout=5 dbname=NexentaSearch user=DKOI
 password=21111991");
if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
    puts("Не удается подключиться к базе данных");
    exit(0);
}

res = PQexec(conn, "select path from paths order by id");

if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
    printf("Мы не получили данные");
    exit(0);
}

rec_count = PQntuples(res);

printf("Мы получили %d записей.\n", rec_count);
puts("==========================");

for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
    for (col=0; col<1; col++) {
        fprintf("usr/local/paths.txt", "%s\n", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
    }
    puts("");
}

puts("==========================");
PQclear(res);
PQfinish(conn);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: libc подключен?

Comment: а он (libc) и в Project Explorer должен отображаться?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема не в библиотеках, а в том, что индексатор не видит стандартных инклюдников. Компилятор видит, и поэтому программа успешно компилируется, а сам Eclipse - не видит, и потому не узнаёт стандартные функции. Обычно проблема решается добавлением директории /usr/include в список путей для поиска инклюдников (в настройках проекта).